# Хорошее размытие изображения в GD

Tags: php, изображения, gd

На сайте имеется скрипт генерации миниатюр. Поскольку он изначально на GD, я добавил несколько строк, чтобы имитировать тень:

```
$background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 239, 239, 239);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 170, 170, 170);

//рисуем фон
imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);
//рисуем тень
imagefilledrectangle($this->image, $xpos-0, $ypos, $width-$xpos+0, $height-$ypos+0, $shadow);

//размываем тень
imagefilter($this->image, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);    
//накладываем поверх изображение
imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $this->width, $this->height);
```

Получается что-то вроде этого (если не накладывать изображение поверх):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR` не настраивается. Т.е силу размытия (она довольно небольшая) изменить нельзя. Мне нужно размытие увеличить на много больше (хотябы 50-100 px):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал запустить фильтр несколько раз (решение из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245710/php-gd-better-gaussian-blur)), но все равно тень недостаточно размыта. Да и нагрузка на процессор идет большая, для хостинга это неприемлемый вариант.

Какое решение можно предложить? Тень из наложенных друг на друга прямоугольников с отступом не предлагать, она слишком ненатурально выглядит из-за острых углов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размытие серого прямоугольника хоть и очень логичный, но не самый эффективный способ создать тень. За эффективностью предлагаю обратиться к опыту игроделов и "растянуть" тень из пары пикселей в большую картинку. При наличии сглаживания (интерполяции) это способ получить довольно качественное размытие с меньшими затратами, в отличие от размытия. Проблема кроется в том, что `imagecopyresampled` не делает интерполяцию при увеличении размеров, только при уменьшении. При увеличинии - только nearest neighbour, т.е. дублирование пикселей.

В PHP 5.5 появилась функция [imagesetinterpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetinterpolation.php), которая управляет тем самым размытием. По документации, её эффект заметен только на функциях [imageaffine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageaffine.php) и `imagerotate`. Первая возволяет делать "произвольные" [аффинные преобразования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), чем мы и воспользуемся.

С помощью аффинного преобразования функция imageaffine создаст нам новое изображение из старого путём перетаскивания пикселей на новые места, в соответствии с заданными линейными уравнениями. Всё пространство между пикселями в новой картинке будет заполнено с помощью метода интерполяции, который устанавливается imagesetinterpolation.

Далее немного магии.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Создаём фоновое изображение
$width = 480;
$height = 320;
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// Создаём изображение для тени
$shadow_downscale = 40;
$shadow_upscale = 10;
$shadow_width = $width / $shadow_downscale;
$shadow_height = $height / $shadow_downscale;
$shadow_image = imagecreatetruecolor($shadow_width, $shadow_height);
imagesetinterpolation($shadow_image, IMG_BSPLINE);

// Цвета
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 239, 239, 239);
$shadow = imagecolorallocate($image, 170, 170, 170);

// Рисуем фон
imagefilledrectangle($image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);

// Рисуем тень как вложенный прямоугольник на фоне
imagefilledrectangle($shadow_image, 0, 0, $shadow_width, $shadow_height, $background);
imagefilledrectangle($shadow_image, 2, 2, $shadow_width-2, $shadow_height-2, $shadow);

// Размываем тень
$rendered_shadow = imageaffine($shadow_image, array($shadow_upscale,0,0,$shadow_upscale,0,0));
$rendered_shadow_width = imagesx($rendered_shadow);
$rendered_shadow_height = imagesy($rendered_shadow);

// Накладываем поверх изображения
$xpos = 40; $ypos = 40;
imagecopyresampled($image, $rendered_shadow, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, $width - 2*$xpos, $height - 2*$ypos, $rendered_shadow_width, $rendered_shadow_height);

imagepng($image);
?>
```

Замечания по коду:

- Сила "размытия" управляется лишь отношением разметров "теневой" картинки к основной. Уменьшение в 40 раз - значит и радиус около 40.
- Из предлагаемых интерполяцией фильтров мне больше всего понравился IMG_BSPLINE, но даже он даёт некоторую "засветку" по краям. Имеет смысл в финальном этапе копирования вырезать нужный диапазон с минимумом побочных эффектов.
- imageaffine создаёт новое изображение, и его размеры определяются границами преобразований. Чем меньше коэффициенты масштабирования, тем меньше создаваемая картинка и меньше нагрузка на хостера. Так вот, необязательно делать upscale до размеров исходной картинки. Ввиду общей размытости, даже в 4 раза меньшая картинка с "тенью" даёт вменяемый результат.
- Со значениями всё равно придётся шаманить.

Результат:

[image: Тень]

Comment: В целом работает, но вылазит какая-то странная полоска внизу толщиной в оригинальный пиксель. Вообщем, ложка дегтя в бочке меда. Решил это просто добавив пару пикселей на обрезку. А так, метод огонь, спасибо, как только можно будет отдать награду сразу передам.

Answer (score -1):

Для такого размытия можно попробовать модуль `imagick`.

Вот мануал про установку модуля [imagick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iBul.jpg)

А это пример как работает этот фильтр:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('[![http://flashyroki.ru/3d_kub/image1.jpg][2]][2]');
$image->blurImage(30,300);
echo $image;

?>
```

Вот исходная картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это картинка после работы фильтра:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Работу кода можете посмотреть [здесь](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cnheader('Content-type:%20image/jpeg');%5Cn%5Cn$image%20=%20new%20Imagick('http://flashyroki.ru/3d_kub/image1.jpg');%5Cn$image-%3EblurImage(40,400);%5Cnecho%20$image;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E).

Подробно о `imagick` можете прочитать [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/imagick.blurimage.php).

Comment: 1) нужно GD, а imagick, решение на imagic не сложно найти. 2) Установка модуля на хостинге? 3) фильтр размытия box выглядит тоже плохо.

Comment: @Crantisz Вообще каждая функция `php` для размытия изображения грузит процессор, вам точно надо все это на `php` сделать? или можно будет на `html` ? и 3-ий вариант сделать размытие каждого изображения один раз и сохранить его для повторного использования.

Comment: Естественно, изображения кешируются.

Comment: @Crantisz и все ровно нагрузку на процессор не снимешь если так размыть изображения с помощью `php`.